Rich text field images are not rendering in Salesforce mobile app
Need expert help for our unique scenario related to Salesforce Mobile App
I am having a Rich Text Area field in my account object, in which I am storing an image. We have a community portal where we are displaying the Account records using LWC.
The images from the Rich Text Area field are rendering when viewed from Desktop. When we tested from the Mobile view of Desktop browser the images were still loading. Attached is the screenshot of the same

But when we tested the same by installing the Publisher Playground app in our Mobile Phone, the images are not rendering.
Attached image reference for the same

Given below is the source code for the same
<template if:true={photo.image1}>
                <div class="image-item slds-large-size_4-of-12 slds-medium-size_3-of-12 slds-size_12-of-12 slds-p-right_medium">
                    <div><span class="image-text"><b class="uppercase">MEN'S {photo.title} RL</b></span></div>
                    <div class="photo-image"><img src={photo.image1} alt={photo.title}  width={labels.Image_Width} height={labels.Image_height} class="img-fluid" loading="lazy"  /></div>
                </div>
                </template>
                <template if:true={photo.image2}>
                <div class="image-item slds-large-size_4-of-12 slds-medium-size_3-of-12 slds-size_12-of-12 slds-p-right_medium">
                    <div ><span class="image-text"><b class="uppercase">WOMEN'S {photo.title} RL</b></span></div>
                  <div  class="photo-image"> <img src={photo.image2} alt={photo.title}   width={labels.Image_Width} height={labels.Image_height} loading="lazy" /></div>
                </div>
                </template>

The Account record is retrieved via standard apex code and passed onto the LWC JS.
We have My Domain enabled in our Org. Also, have CDN for Lightning Component Framework enabled.
We did found a solution but made the Rich Text Area field images visible in the Mobile app but that is not optimal for our use case. Below is the solution details
**

Go to Files
Upload a new file with the image desired.
Open the image, at the top there is a link called: public link
Create the public link if there isn’t yet
Click create
Copy the link
Open it in a new browser tab
Right click, “Copy image”
Go to the Rich text field, paste the image in the rich text field .
Save it. Image should be available for login and guest users**

We Couldn't find anything else in google and hence posting the question here.
Can someone help please?
